# How to monitor and stop running tasks separately using tpl

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to parallel programming and tpl in c# and I am doing the following test in order to see how tasks work. Each time I click the button1 and the bounded method is fired, a new task will start. When I click button_2 all tasks will exit the loop and I will get the time elapsed for all tasks and there task id.

So is there a way to monitor these tasks while they are working in a task pool so I can stop them if I wish separately using the Task Id?

```
        Boolean stopprogramm = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Task timerTask1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                    watch.Start();
                    while (stopprogramm == false)
                    {
                        //Do some work
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("time ellapsed for No partitioning at all version {0}ms , thread id was {1}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, Task.CurrentId);
                    watch.Stop();

                });


        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopprogramm = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in one of the comments from my other answer a link, it looks like that link describes how to make it cancellable.  I have adapted my example to support this:

```
    private Dictionary<Guid, TaskTracker> _taskMap = new Dictionary<Guid, TaskTracker>();

    private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        TaskTracker taskTracker = new TaskTracker(Guid.NewGuid(), OnDoWork);
        _taskMap.Add(taskTracker.Identity, taskTracker);
        taskTracker.Start();
    }

    private void OnDoWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // Do some work, checking if cancel requested every once in a while
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnButton2Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Guid identity = _taskMap.Count > 0 ? _taskMap.First().Value.Identity : default(Guid);  // find some way to get the desired task

        TaskTracker taskTracker;
        if (_taskMap.TryGetValue(identity, out taskTracker))
        {
            taskTracker.TaskExiting += OnTaskExiting;
            taskTracker.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void OnTaskExiting(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        TaskTracker taskTracker = (TaskTracker)sender;
        taskTracker.TaskExiting -= OnTaskExiting;
        _taskMap.Remove(taskTracker.Identity);

        Console.WriteLine("Time ellapsed for No partitioning at all version {0}ms , thread id was {1}", taskTracker.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, Task.CurrentId);
    }

    private void OnButton3Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Guid identity = _taskMap.Count > 0 ? _taskMap.First().Value.Identity : default(Guid);  // find some way to get the desired task

        TaskTracker taskTracker;
        if (_taskMap.TryGetValue(identity, out taskTracker))
        {
            taskTracker.TaskExiting += OnTaskExiting;
            taskTracker.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

And here is the TaskTracker class:

```
public class TaskTracker
{
    private readonly Action<CancellationToken> OnDoWork;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource TokenSource;
    private readonly CancellationToken Token;

    private bool _isRunning;
    private Task _task;

    public TaskTracker(Guid identity, Action<CancellationToken> onDoWork)
    {
        TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Token = TokenSource.Token;

        Identity = identity;
        OnDoWork = onDoWork;
    }

    public readonly Guid Identity;
    public readonly Stopwatch Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public event EventHandler TaskExiting;

    public void Start()
    {
        _isRunning = true;
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
                {
                    Stopwatch.Start();
                    try
                    {
                        while (_isRunning)
                        {
                            OnDoWork(Token);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Stopwatch.Stop();

                        if (TaskExiting != null)
                        {
                            TaskExiting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                        }
                    }
                }, Token
            );
    }

    public void Stop(bool waitForTaskToExit = false)
    {
        if (_task == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Task hasn't been started yet");
        }

        _isRunning = false;
        if (waitForTaskToExit)
        {
            _task.Wait();
        }
        _task = null;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        if (_task == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Task hasn't been started yet");
        }

        _isRunning = false;
        TokenSource.Cancel();
        _task = null;
    }
}
```

Basically, in your "Worker" you would check to see if the token indicates it is being cancelled, if so do some cleanup and then call the method ThrowIfCancellationRequested on token to break out.

Comment: One thing to mention is, that even if the task stops, and monitoring is viable now, the OnDoWork wont get the token in order to stop the actuall work. I will try to figure it out, since the task is not running as I can see from the watcher. If I can't find it out I will post a new question since it is a new issue. Thank you  again

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work.

```
    private Dictionary<Guid, TaskTracker> _taskMap = new Dictionary<Guid, TaskTracker>();

    private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        TaskTracker taskTracker = new TaskTracker(Guid.NewGuid(), OnDoWork);
        _taskMap.Add(taskTracker.Identity, taskTracker);
        taskTracker.Run();
    }

    private void OnDoWork()
    {
        // Do some work
    }

    private void OnButton2Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Guid identity = _taskMap.Count > 0 ? _taskMap.First().Value.Identity : default(Guid);  // find some way to get the desired task

        TaskTracker taskTracker;
        if (_taskMap.TryGetValue(identity, out taskTracker))
        {
            taskTracker.TaskExiting += OnTaskExiting;
            taskTracker.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void OnTaskExiting(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        TaskTracker taskTracker = (TaskTracker)sender;
        taskTracker.TaskExiting -= OnTaskExiting;
        _taskMap.Remove(taskTracker.Identity);
        // do what you want with the timings
    }
```

The class for task is this:

```
public class TaskTracker
{
    private readonly Action OnDoWork;
    private Task _task;
    private bool _isRunning = true;

    public TaskTracker(Guid identity, Action onDoWork)
    {
        Identity = identity;
        OnDoWork = onDoWork;
    }

    public readonly Guid Identity;
    public readonly Stopwatch Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public event EventHandler TaskExiting;

    public void Run()
    {
        Task _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
                {
                    Stopwatch.Start();
                    try
                    {
                        while (_isRunning)
                        {
                            OnDoWork();
                        }
                        if (TaskExiting != null)
                        {
                            TaskExiting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Stopwatch.Stop();
                    }
                }
            );
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _isRunning = false;
        // wait for task to exit?
        _task = null;
    }
}
```

You will need to fill in the blanks, meaning tracking tasks and getting the target task when hitting button 2.

Comment: looks neat , but .Net 4.0 has the Task keyword already reserved because of tpl?, But I am looking at the Dictionary taskmap and it triggers my thought to use something like that to monitor my running tasks. But I will test it anyway, thank you

Comment: I haven't ever used this class.  I revised my answer to maybe be more of what you were looking for.  The TaskTracker class wraps the Task object and manages time tracking.

Comment: Ok the class works, The dictionary indeed helps me monitor my active tasks. Only one issue remains, how to stop one of the n tasks. The stop method doesn't seem to stop any task

Comment: Try this revision out, the Stop method doesn't wait for the task to exit, so it doesn't block the UI thread.  So I added an event that is fired when it exits out of the Task method.

Comment: No still does not stop any tasks. I found that it need something like IsCancellationRequested. I am reading it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Also thank you for all your effort

Comment: Sorry its working, I had some extra code outside and I misunderstood what was really happening. I put the watcher on and I saw that the first task is not running and I can stop at will each task that I need. So this class works perfectly

Comment: I fixed it so it would remove the trackers after they were completed.  Also I added another answer with a different example, that supports cancellation.